# Flutter - SQLite deadlock just in FIRST RUN of the app

Tags: sql, sqlite, dart, flutter

I was trying to create a database and after create and insert some data, get this data from a `SELECT`.

But in the first time that a try to open app I create the tables and after this don't move to the next screen, I stay in this screen forever:

[Infinite load screen on FIRST RUN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugd4N.jpg)

[this return from initDB methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJl0r.png)

My database class:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';


import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

class ConfigDatabase {
  static final ConfigDatabase _instance = ConfigDatabase._internal();

  factory ConfigDatabase() => _instance;

  static Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDB();
    return _db;
  }

  ConfigDatabase._internal();

  Future<Database> initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "sagres_relatorios.db");
    var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return theDb;
  }

  void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE Empresa ("
            " EmpresaId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            " Nome TEXT,"
            " ipServidorGestao TEXT,"
            " portaServidorGestao TEXT,"
            " ipServidorVendas TEXT,"
            " portaServidorVendas TEXT,"
            " CNPJ TEXT,"
            " SenhaREST TEXT,"
            " Selecionado BIT);");
    print("Tabela Empresa Criada!");
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE ConfigAtual ("
            " EmpresaId INTEGER,"
            " SessaoGuidId TEXT,"
            " Operador TEXT,"
            " isChecked BIT,"
            " FOREIGN KEY(EmpresaId) REFERENCES Empresa(EmpresaId)"
            ");");
    print("Tabela ConfigAtual Criada!");
    initPrimeirosDados();
    print("Primeiros Dados init");
  }

  uptade(String Nome, String ipServidorGestao, String portaServidorGestao, String ipServidorVendas, String portaServidorVendas,
      String CNPJ, String SenhaREST, int EmpresaId) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    int count = await dbClient.rawUpdate(
        'UPDATE Empresa SET Nome = ?, ipServidorGestao = ?, portaServidorGestao = ?, ipServidorVendas = ?, portaServidorVendas = ?,'
            ' CNPJ = ?, SenhaREST = ? WHERE EmpresaId = $EmpresaId',
        [Nome, ipServidorGestao, portaServidorGestao, ipServidorVendas, portaServidorVendas, CNPJ, SenhaREST]);
    return count;
  }

  insertEmpresa(String Nome, String ipServidorGestao, String portaServidorGestao,
      String ipServidorVendas, String portaServidorVendas, String CNPJ, String SenhaREST) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    int count = await dbClient.rawUpdate(
        'INSERT INTO Empresa(Nome, ipServidorGestao, portaServidorGestao, ipServidorVendas, portaServidorVendas, CNPJ, SenhaREST) VALUES'
            '("$Nome", "$ipServidorGestao", "$portaServidorGestao", "$ipServidorVendas", "$portaServidorVendas", "$CNPJ", "$SenhaREST")');
    return count;
  }

  uptadeSessao(String SessaoGuidId) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    int count = await dbClient.rawUpdate(
        'UPDATE ConfigAtual SET SessaoGuidId = ?',
        [SessaoGuidId]);
    return count;
  }

  updateLembrarDeMim(String Operador) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    await dbClient.rawUpdate(
        'UPDATE ConfigAtual SET Operador = ?',
        [Operador]);

  }

  updateIsChecked(int isChecked) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    await dbClient.rawUpdate(
        'UPDATE ConfigAtual SET isChecked = ?',
        [isChecked]);

  }

  updateConfigAtual(int EmpresaId) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    await dbClient.rawUpdate(
        'UPDATE ConfigAtual SET EmpresaId = ?',
        [EmpresaId]);
    await dbClient.rawUpdate(
        'UPDATE Empresa SET Selecionado = 0');
    await dbClient.rawUpdate(
        'UPDATE Empresa SET Selecionado = 1 WHERE EmpresaId = ?',
        [EmpresaId]);
  }

  Future<List<Map>> carregarListEmpresas() async{
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT e.ipServidorGestao, e.portaServidorGestao, e.CNPJ, e.SenhaREST, c.SessaoGuidId '
        'FROM Empresa E '
        'JOIN ConfigAtual C on e.EmpresaId = c.EmpresaId');
    return list;
  }

  Future<ResultConfig> loadLoginPage() async{
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery
      ('SELECT isChecked, Operador FROM ConfigAtual');
    ResultConfig BD = new ResultConfig.fromJson(list[0]);
    return BD;
  }


  initPrimeirosDados() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    int res = await dbClient.transaction((txn) async {
      await txn.rawInsert(
          'INSERT INTO ConfigAtual(EmpresaId, Operador, isChecked) VALUES(1, "Supervisor", 1)');
      await txn.rawInsert(
          'INSERT INTO Empresa(Nome, ipServidorGestao, portaServidorGestao, ipServidorVendas, portaServidorVendas, CNPJ, SenhaREST, Selecionado) VALUES'
              '("Sagres Informática", "192.168.0.1", "999", "20", "999", "00.000.000/0000-00", "48965", 1)');
    });

    return res;
  }

  insertCNPJ(String CNPJ, String Descricao) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    int res = await dbClient.transaction((txn) async {
      await txn.rawInsert(
          'INSERT INTO CNPJ(CNPJ, Descricao) VALUES("$CNPJ", "$Descricao")');
    });
    return res;
  }

  deleteEmpresa(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    int res = await dbClient.transaction((txn) async {
      await txn.rawInsert(
          "DELETE FROM Empresa WHERE EmpresaId  = '$id'");
    });
    return res;
  }

  Future closeDb() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    dbClient.close();
  }

}

class ResultConfig {
  ResultConfig({
    this.EmpresaId,
    this.Nome,
    this.ipServidorGestao,
    this.portaServidorGestao,
    this.ipServidorVendas,
    this.portaServidorVendas,
    this.CNPJ,
    this.SenhaREST,
    this.SessaoGuidId,
    this.Selecionado,
    this.Operador,
    this.isChecked
  });


  int EmpresaId, Selecionado, isChecked;
  String Nome, ipServidorGestao, portaServidorGestao, ipServidorVendas, portaServidorVendas, CNPJ, SenhaREST, SessaoGuidId, Operador;

  factory ResultConfig.fromJson(Map json) {
    //returns a List of Maps
    return new ResultConfig(
      EmpresaId: json['EmpresaId'],
      Nome: json['Nome'],
      ipServidorGestao: json['ipServidorGestao'],
      portaServidorGestao: json['portaServidorGestao'],
      ipServidorVendas: json['ipServidorVendas'],
      portaServidorVendas: json['portaServidorVendas'],
      CNPJ: json['CNPJ'],
      SenhaREST: json['SenhaREST'],
      SessaoGuidId: json['SessaoGuidId'],
      Selecionado: json['Selecionado'],
      Operador: json['Operador'],
      isChecked: json['isChecked'],
    );
  }

}
```

But, after I close and open APP, it runs perfect forever, until I erase app and reinstall.

After reopening the app, I get this screen, my loginPage.

[LoginPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT6eF.jpg)

Does anyone know how to run the LoginPage right the first time I open the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, when the db is not created you get infinitive loop because of `initPrimeirosDados()` - you call it from `_onCreate()` which is called from `initDB()` which is called from `get db()` and you call this getter again in `initPrimeirosDados()`.

So, just inline this function in `_onCreate()` or pass `Database db` as parameter

```
  initPrimeirosDados(Database dbClient) async {
    int res = await dbClient.transaction((txn) async {
      await txn.rawInsert(
          'INSERT INTO ConfigAtual(EmpresaId, Operador, isChecked) VALUES(1, "Supervisor", 1)');
      await txn.rawInsert(
          'INSERT INTO Empresa(Nome, ipServidorGestao, portaServidorGestao, ipServidorVendas, portaServidorVendas, CNPJ, SenhaREST, Selecionado) VALUES'
              '("Sagres Informática", "192.168.0.1", "999", "20", "999", "00.000.000/0000-00", "48965", 1)');
    });

    return res;
  }
```

Comment: Hey Marica, thanks so much, this code worked like a charm! Thanks too much!